# Changing font color of specific language in ms word

Tags: ms-word

Hi I am having a word document that contains two languages in it.(e.g. English and Chinese) I am currently manually changing all the Chinese words into another font colour one by one. Are there any ways that I can change all of them in one go?

Answer (score 1):

If your English and Chinese content employ different Styles (which they should), all you need do is change the font colour in the Style definition. This is far more reliable and robust than using Find/Replace; it also automatically applies to any content you add to the document after making the Style change.